# Can SQL Server execute a small C program?

Tags: c, sql-server

I have some strings I process using T-SQL as part of a bigger SQL Server project but I think I could speed up the process considerably if I could get SQL Server to run some C on it for me. Is this possible?

EDIT:

As requested in the comments here is the function in T-SQL that I am thinking of rewriting in C or C# (never used C# before though). It just removes non alphanumeric characters from a string but we are applying it over a huge dataset and I want to see if I can speed it up, having done similar things with C in the past.

```
  Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
  Set @KeepValues = '%[^a-z0-9]%'
  While PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp) > 0
      Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues, @Temp), 1, '')

  Return @Temp
```

Comment: Lookup CLR functions. It will be C#/VB.net, not C, but should still be fast. What do you actually need to do, it may be possible in T-SQL only

Comment: You can run any command-line program on the db server via T-SQL using xp_cmdshell. Whether or not you should is another story.

Comment: You can create extended stored procedures in C, but this feature will be deprecated.
As @Charlieface said, use CLR Integration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-stored-procedures-programming/creating-extended-stored-procedures?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @DanGuzman Please no. Powershell via an Agent job if you have to, just not `xp_cmdshell`

Comment: @Charlieface "Whether or not you should is another story."

Comment: @DanGuzman I mean to say "Don't even mention it, it's that bad"

Comment: Haha OK no  xp_cmdshell, I will try CLR functions to see what performance improvement I can get. Thank you.

Comment: "...

I have some strings I process using T-SQL..." Please share what it is about.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I have added the code I was planning to write to be more efficient in C.